# Looking for a book, blog or feed about anti-patterns

Tags: anti-patterns, knowledge-transfer

In my experience, being familiar with anti-patterns is as vital as knowing patterns themselves.

Despite an abundance of literature on patterns, there is a surprising lack of literature on anti-patterns. Browsing the web usually reveals advises that are either too vague (e.g. "*do not use global variables*"), too specific (e.g. "*java.lang.Boolean.getBoolean doesn't do what you think it does*") or obviously wrong to begin with (e.g. *God object*).

What I am looking for are anti-patterns that appear to be good solutions at first glance, but tend to lead to issues further down the line.

Do you know any good source of such anti-patterns? (the only good example I know is [SQL Antipatterns](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1934356557))

Comment: Why does everything these days have to be a pattern? And by extension, the bad things be an anti-pattern?

Comment: There are many contenders, but most people will still do a search  at http://c2.com/cgi/wiki for discussions and viewpoints from the gurus of the last decade.

Comment: @Pieter Why can I only +1 you a single time!?

Comment: @PieterB, there is an easy explanation for the recent surge in interest in the so called "patterns": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apophenia

Comment: Did you try searching Amazon.com for "antipatterns"?

Answer (score 4):

> being familiar with anti-patterns is as vital as knowing patterns
>   themselves

**I agree!** If you are avoiding all the anti-patterns then you are probably following the good patterns.

I recently took interest in finding anti-patterns and came across [Wikipedia's Anti-Pattern Examples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern#Examples) which has a large categorized list of anti-patterns and I wanted an alphabetical listing so I put all of them into an [alphabetical list](http://koreyhinton.wordpress.com/2013/08/15/what-are-anti-patterns/) on my [blog](http://www.koreyhinton.com).

Related terms: [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell), [dark patterns](http://www.90percentofeverything.com/2010/07/08/dark-patterns-dirty-tricks-designers-use-to-make-people-do-stuff/), [common programming pitfalls](http://www.90percentofeverything.com/2010/07/08/dark-patterns-dirty-tricks-designers-use-to-make-people-do-stuff/), [bad programming practices](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31011/Bad-coding-Practices)

---

### Anti-patterns that might seem like a good idea at first:

- [premature optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimization_%28computer_science%29#When_to_optimize)
- [overengineering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overengineering)
- [interface bloat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_bloat)
- [coding by exception](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coding_by_exception)

Comment: Unfortunately, the anti-patterns mentioned at Wikipedia hardly fulfill "appear to be good solutions at first glance" part.

Comment: @MarosUrbanec Just like patterns are applied based on the context of the problem I think that solutions that "appear to be good solutions at first glance" but aren't will also have to be taken on a case by base basis. Using a particular architecture might be considered a good solution in one context but when used in another context would be considered "overengineering".